# Prove that $\det\left(I_kp - Az\right) =\det\left(I_k - A_1z - \dots - A_pz^p\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, self-learning

Let $A_1\dots A_p$ be real $k\times k$ matrices, and define $kp\times kp$ matrix $Az$ as
\begin{bmatrix}
A_1z & A_2z & A_3z &\dots &A_{p-1}z & A_pz \\
I_kz & 0    & 0    &\dots &0        & 0    \\
0 & I_kz    & 0    &\dots &0        & 0    \\
\vdots      & \vdots & \vdots &\dots &\vdots &\vdots \\
0           & 0    &0  &\dots &I_kz &0
\end{bmatrix}
where $z$ is a scalar.

In the [Lutkepohl's (2005)](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540401728) book it is stated that one can (easily) prove that  $$\det(I_{kp} - Az) = \det(I_k - A_1z - \dots - A_pz^p)$$

So far I have
$$
\det(I_{kp} - Az) = \det
\begin{bmatrix}
I_k - A_1z & -A_2z & -A_3z &\dots &-A_{p-1}z & -A_pz \\
-I_kz & I_k    & 0    &\dots &0        & 0    \\
0 & -I_kz    & I_k    &\dots &0        & 0    \\
\vdots      & \vdots & \vdots &\dots &\vdots &\vdots \\
0           & 0    &0  &\dots &-I_kz &I_k
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I guess that one should apply suitable property of the determinants but I have troubles in finding such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your determinant perform column operations in blocks, adding into the first block column the second block column times $z$, the third times $z^2$ and so on. That will give you
$$
 \det
\begin{bmatrix}
I_k  - A_1z - \dots - A_pz^p & -A_2z & -A_3z &\dots &-A_{p-1}z & -A_pz \\
0 & I_k    & 0    &\dots &0        & 0    \\
0 & -I_kz    & I_k    &\dots &0        & 0    \\
\vdots      & \vdots & \vdots &\dots &\vdots &\vdots \\
0           & 0    &0  &\dots &-I_kz &I_k
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which gives
$$\det(I_k  - A_1z - \dots - A_pz^p)(\det I_k)^{p-1}$$
as required.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second expression, $\det (I_k - A_1z - \dots - A_pz^p)(\det I_k)^{p-1}$, why it follows?

Comment: You need to check out once and for all that $$\det\left[\begin{array}{cc}A & B\\O&D\end{array}\right]$$ is $\det A \det D$. I think you'll find this in the books, it's too complicated to write in a comments box.